# During msi installation 0xc0150002 error occur

Tags: c#, .net, dll, windows-installer

I have an own .msi agent for windows machines. I have bundled latest (1.0.1h) openssl dll (ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll).
During msi installation in windows 2003 server below error occurs.

**Application failed to initialize properly 0xc0150002**

In Error log :

> General Activation context failed for C:....\bin\SSLEAY32.dll.
>   Reference error message. The reserenced assembly is not installed on
>   your system.

P.S : This problem did not occur for old openssl dll.

Comment: This looks more like a statement and not like a question. Could you be more specific?

Comment: is there .net framework dependency in latest openssl? What is the solution to install the msi without these error?

Comment: Im 99% sure that Windows Installer doesn't need those Dlls, so I suspect that you are running a program as a custom action. If so, you need to specify things like what type of custom action, where you are running it and so on.

Comment: Msi used to scan some hardware entry and send to the server through tcp protocol. For secure ssl connection Im using openssl dll.